# Параметр/переменная в WHERE в IN

Tags: sql-server

Необходимо переделать процедуру, сейчас она формирует результат так :
 `dateDocument between @dateOne and @dateTwo`, тут все понятно проблем нет.
 Я хочу что бы можно было формировать только по id, так
 `WHERE dataRegistr.id IN (@id)`
Вопрос, как в @id передать несколько значений? Примитивно методом тыка не затащило :

```
declare @test varchar(200) = '85,86,87';
EXEC report @test
```

Comment: Есть методы позволяющие по запятой разделить на отдельные елементы, однин через charindex второй через xml. Но лично мне бы хотелось узнать как всётаки через массив, CristalReport поддерживает массив, но его код закрыт.

Comment: можно использовать табличный тип для параметра.

Comment: @nick_n_a у вас нет примера? Я что то не догоняю как через charindex это сделать.

Comment: @Ruslan_K типо делать INSERT во временную таблицу а потом оттуда доставать в IN?

Comment: Вот на en.so http://stackoverflow.com/a/16664442/5727271, но на xml гораздо компактней;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал так :
В процедуру передаю к примеру `@test varchar(max) = '44,42,4,6,8'` в процедуре :

Это в самом верху процедуры  :

```
select @test ='select '''+replace(@test , ',', ''' as val union all select ''')+''''
declare @t table(id int identity, val varchar(100))
insert into @t
exec (@test )
```

Во всех `WHERE` где есть `IN` делаю так, например :

```
 WHERE id IN (select val from @t where val!='')
```

Answer (score 1):

В SQL Server с версии 2008 есть [Table-Valued Parameters](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine), которые позволяют передавать в процедуры табличные данные.

Через них можно передать сразу пачку ID, примерно так:

```
CREATE TYPE IDList AS TABLE   
( ID INT );  
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SomeProcedure
    @ids IDList READONLY  
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE TaskID IN (SELECT Id FROM @ids)
GO  

DECLARE @someIDs AS IDList;  

INSERT INTO @someIDs
VALUES (1),(2),(3)

EXEC SomeProcedure @someIDs
GO
```